# HTML5 canvas hittesting

Tags: html, canvas, hittest

I have some images drawn on a HTML5 Canvas and I want to check if they are hit on mouse click. Seems easy, I have the bounds of the images, however the images are transformed (translated and scaled). Unfortunately, the context does not have a method to get the current transform matrix, and also, there is no API for matrices multiplication.
Seems the only solution is to keep track of the transforms myself and implement matrix multiplication.
Suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: After more thinking, I have realized that even if the context had a method to get the current transformation matrix, it would not be useful, since I need the image transform matrix on mouse clicking and by that time the context has a different transform.
What I probably need is a scene graph, either implement a simple one or use a library like Cake JS.

Comment: You don't need matrices to translate and scale. For example, to translate and scale a mouse X coordinate, use newPointX = event.x * scaleX + translateX

Comment: Thanks, you are right, in this case I don't have to implement matrix multiplication.

Comment: Somebody started coding a scene graph for Canvas:
http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2010/12/easel-js-simplifies-working-with-canvas-in-html5.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a common problem in the 3D (OpenGL) graphics world as well.

The solution is to create an auxiliary  canvas object (which is not displayed), and to redraw your image into it.  The draw is exactly the same as with your main canvas draw, except that each element gets drawn with a unique color.  You then look up the pixel corresponding to your mouse pick, and read off its color, which will give you the corresponding element (if any).

This is a commonly used method in the OpenGL world.  You can find descriptions of it by Googling terms like ["opengl object picking"](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=opengl+object+picking).  Here is [one of the many search results](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html#name6).

**Update:** The HTML5 canvas spec now includes [hit regions](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#hit-regions).  I'm not sure to what degree these are supported by browsers yet.

Comment: The issue here is that the canvases all do non optional color blending and anti aliasing. Resulting in in between colors when the objects abut each other. These in between colors can fall close enough to other color ids you have stored that a border area can get misrepresented as a hit for a different object. I'm unsure the best way to get around this. Using a separate canvas per detectable object wastes too much memory, and rendering each object separately while the mouse is moving and checking seems like it will waste too much performance.